# How to get Next available Date in MDX

Tags: mdx

I would like to get next available date for next month based on working day.
I am using Businessday = 1 as a working day.

Next available date for September is 09/03/2019 for running MDX on 08/31/2019.
I tried:

```
[Time].[Date].NextMember.MEMBER_VALUE
```

without any filter and it returns 09/1/2019.

If I do

```
[Time].[Date].LEAD(2).MEMBER_VALUE
```

then it give 09/02/2019 but this date is not marked as a business day according to my Businessday = 1
The result should be 09/03/2019

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example that I made on Adventure Works cube - just instead of `Businessday` measure I am using  `[Measures].[Internet Order Count]` measure.

So, in this example, for each month, calculated member `[Measures].[NextWorkingDay]` is showing first date in the next month that has `Internet Order Count = 8` (you will just say `Businessday = 1`)

```
   WITH MEMBER [Measures].[NextWorkingDay] AS
       FILTER(Descendants([Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.Lead(1),,leaves)
            , [Measures].[Internet Order Count]= 8).ITEM(0).NAME
   SELECT { [Measures].[NextWorkingDay]
       } ON 0,
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON 1
   FROM [Adventure Works]
```

[image]